# Regexp is not working as expected in unix

Tags: regex, xml, pcre

I am trying with below code and its not working as expcted. I am new to REGEX. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<audit>
    <interfaces>
        <interface_dtls>ABCD,ABCD 123</interface_dtls>
        <interface_dtls>TESTING,123 TEST</interface_dtls>
    </interfaces>
</audit>
```

Trying with below unix commands

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `cat  test.xml | grep -oP "(?<=interface_dtls>)[^<]+"`; do
    echo $line  --Displaying line only for debugging purpose
    interface_code=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`
    prcdr_cd=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
    hive -e "select * from table \
    where sub_sys_cd='$interface_code' and data_prcdr_desc='$prcdr_cd';"
done
```

Actual "ECHO" output:

```
ABCD,ABCD
TESTING,123
```

Expected "ECHO" output:

```
ABCD,ABCD 123
TESTING,123 TEST
```

Becuse of missing info(info after space) my query is not working as expected.

Comment: No need to use `cat` or `for` loop, just `grep -oP '(?<=interface_dtls>)[^<]+' test.xml` would do it

Comment: @anubhava: A few seconds late and you beat me to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little bit of research i am able to resolve the issue. But thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian , https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941495/kusalananda and https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava for helpful insights.

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<audit>
    <interfaces>
        <interface_dtls>ABCD,ABCD 123</interface_dtls>
        <interface_dtls>TESTING,123 TEST</interface_dtls>
    </interfaces>
</audit>
```

Before:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `cat  test.xml | grep -oP "(?<=interface_dtls>)[^<]+"`; do
    echo $line  --Displaying line only for debugging purpose
    interface_code=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`
    prcdr_cd=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
    hive -e "select * from table \
    where sub_sys_cd='$interface_code' and data_prcdr_desc='$prcdr_cd';"
done
```

After:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='$\n'
for line in `cat  test.xml | grep -oP "(?<=interface_dtls>)[^<]+" | cut -d '>' -f 2 | cut -d '<' -f 1`; do
    echo $line  --Displaying line only for debugging purpose
    interface_code=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
    prcdr_cd=$(echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}')
    hive -e "select * from table \
    where sub_sys_cd='$interface_code' and data_prcdr_desc='$prcdr_cd';"
done
```

"ECHO" output:

```
ABCD,ABCD 123
TESTING,123 TEST
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`xml_grep`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep), the more recommended option for parsing, as `grep` is not not an `XML` aware tool.

```
$ xml_grep 'interface_dtls' file --text_only
ABCD,ABCD 123
TESTING,123 TEST
```

One could also use `grep` as pointed by [`anubhava`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) over in comments. Probably not the best of ways to do it, but can done for a one-time debug. For proper functionality use any XML readable commands (e.g `xmllint` or `xml_grep`).

```
$ grep -oP "(?<=<interface_dtls>)[^<]+" xml_file
ABCD,ABCD 123
TESTING,123 TEST
```

The skeletal code for extracting the individual words from the command can be done as below. I will leave it up to you to tweak it as you need and do not use the outdated `` style command expansion, rather use `$` wherever applicable.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r paramA paramB;
do
    interface_code=$(echo $paramA | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
    prcdr_cd=$(echo $paramA | awk -F ',' '{print $2}')

    echo $interface_code $prcdr_cd

done < <(xml_grep 'interface_dtls' file --text_only)
```

Comment: Thanks Inian. I tried with 1st option you mentioned and it is working fine from command line. But I have to use for loop to build hive query and submit from command line based on the values in <interface_dtls>...</interface_dtls> . So i tried again with below code and it is not working. Im new to unix scripting kindly bare with me.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for line in `grep -oP "(?<=<interface_dtls>)[^<]+"` test.xml ; do
  echo $line
  interface_code=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`
  prcdr_cd=`echo $line | awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
  hive -e "select * from table \
  where sub_sys_cd='$interface_code' and data_prcdr_desc='$prcdr_cd';"
  fi
done

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy; Appreciate your concern, can you update the OP again with the requirement

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy: ive provided a skeletal code for you to try further, I cannot provide the entire code as per the community ethics. Please ensure you accept the answer once you find it useful

Comment: Thanks Inian. I will modify according to my requirement. If possible can you guide me where my current code is going wrong. Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy: Your for-loop syntax may not be accurate, use the skeleton which I shared and construct your query! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `xml_grep` utility was mentioned in another answer. This uses [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), which is also able to validate and modify XML files on the command line:

```
$ xml sel -t -v '//interface_dtls' -nl data.xml
ABCD,ABCD 123
TESTING,123 TEST
```

Comment: it is failing with LPX-00202: could not open "sel" (error 200)

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy It is likely that `xml` on your system (Oracle Linux?) is a totally different utility. Make sure that you actually have XMLStarlet installed and that you know what it's main executable is called. If it's called `xml` then you might have to give the complete path to that executable, so that the *other* `xml` utility isn't run instead.

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy Hold on, you *are* running this on the command line and not in a database client or something silly like that?

Comment: @GokulkrishnaSurapureddy Good, then see my previous comment.